# Java: Class not found for PageRank algorithm in Apache Hadoop

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I am trying to run PageRank algorithm in Apache Hadoop (2.6.5) cluster (1 master 2 slaves). I am using the program in this repository - https://github.com/danielepantaleone/hadoop-pagerank.git. I was able to compile all the sources using this command -

```
sudo javac -classpath ${HADOOP_CLASSPATH} -d ./build src/it/uniroma1/hadoop/pagerank/PageRank.java src/it/uniroma1/hadoop/pagerank/job1/PageRankJob1Mapper.java src/it/uniroma1/hadoop/pagerank/job1/PageRankJob1Reducer.java src/it/uniroma1/hadoop/pagerank/job2/PageRankJob2Mapper.java src/it/uniroma1/hadoop/pagerank/job2/PageRankJob2Reducer.java src/it/uniroma1/hadoop/pagerank/job3/PageRankJob3Mapper.java
```

I created the jar file using this command `sudo jar -cf build/pagerank.jar build/`.

I am trying to run the program just like the wordcount example like this -

```
sudo bin/hadoop jar hadoop-pagerank/build/pagerank.jar PageRank --
input /usr/local/hdfs/web-Google.txt --output /usr/local/hdfs-out-PR
```

Sometimes I get an error like this -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PageRank (wrong name: it/uniroma1/hadoop
/pagerank/PageRank)
```

and sometimes I get an error like this - `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PageRank for different types of compilation.`

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Can anyone please help me in proper steps to compile and run the program in Hadoop ? I dont have any pom.xml file and I am able to run the provided wordcount example jar.

Comment: You need to give the full classname with package. `it.uniroma1.hadoop.pagerank.PageRank`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use package name before the name of the class,
it means you have to use :
`it.uniroma1.hadoop.pagerank.PageRank`

rather than `PageRank` 
in your command. 
like this :

`hadoop jar hadoop-pagerank/build/pagerank.jar it.uniroma1.hadoop.pagerank.PageRank --input /usr/local/hdfs/web-Google.txt --output /usr/local/hdfs-out-PR`